# Como executar(interagir) comandos prompt pelo Java?(Linux e Windows)

Tags: java, ssh, prompt

Eai galera. 
Preciso desenvolver um programa java que execute comandos como se fosse no promt/cmd, e de certa forma ate mesmo interagir com o mesmo.
Sabe quando nós executamos algum tipo de comando no prompt e ele da uma resposta ou pede uma senha? Exatamente isso, preciso de uma função java que eu possa me conectar com um dispositivo via SSH, digitar a senha de acesso. 
E na sequencia rodar todos os comandos que eu precisar para configuração desse dispositivo.
Pesquisando já encontrei algumas coisas, e já até consegui rodar um comando.

**Mas existe um caso, no meu cenário real, onde eu preciso rodar um comando, e logo em seguida o prompt fica esperando a senha, mas não consegui fazer com que o JAVA logo envia-se a senha e eu segui-se com os próximos comandos.

Segue abaixo oque eu já tenho.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     String[] cmds = {
                "ssh -S none admin@ip_aqui"
                /*"admin",
                "enable",
                "senhaaqui",
                "configure terminal",
                "gpon",
                "gpon-olt 1",
                "show onu info" */              
            };

     try {
                //ProcessBuilder a = new Proce
                ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c",
                    String.join("& ", cmds));

                builder.redirectErrorStream(true);

                Process p = builder.start();
                if ( p.waitFor() == 0){
                    System.out.println("Executado.");  
                }               
                else{
                    System.out.println("ERRO");
                }
                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                String line;

                while (true) {
                    line = r.readLine();
                    if (line == null) {
                        break;
                    }

                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
    }
```

No meu array de comandos ali esta comentado pois eu estava testando, mas no caso, após o primeiro comando, o prompt fica esperando a senha, que é o segundo comando, mas o java não consegue enviar a senha no momento correto, ocasionando erro.

Comment: Bom, tente inserior um "builder.join() após inicializar a thread, assim você vai ter certeza que ela executará passo a passo seus comandos até o final.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Alexandre, mas poderia exemplificar melhor.
Meu builder não tem esse metodo join.
E em qual linha seria isso?